# How can I retry scrapy operations before spider finish?

Tags: scrapy, python-3.6

I built sprider by scrapy and python3.6.8 and record uncompleted urls during sprider running:

```
 self.urls.append(url) 

 item=myItem()
 item["mylink"]=url        
 yield scrapy.Request(            
       url="myurl",
       method='GET',
       headers=self.headers,
       callback=self.parse_detail,
       errback=self.make_new_request,
       meta={"item":item})
```

and I try to retry uncompleted urls before spider clsss destroy:

```
def __del__(self):
    print("\033[31myielded:",len(self.yielded),"scrapying:",len(self.urls),"\033[0m")
    if len(self.urls)>0:
        print(self.urls)
        print("\033[31mretry uncompleted\033[0m")
        self.RetryUncompletedUrls()
```

But spider just do print and exist! How can I do retry operations before spider finish? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The retry middleware is enabled by default and is set to retry a URL twice.

You can adjust this in your settings.py file.

```
RETRY_ENABLED = True
RETRY_TIMES = 2
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504, 522, 524, 408, 429]
```